# Use H2-mem as persistence unit

Tags: jpa, h2, java-ee-7, persistence.xml

i'm new in the world of java-ee. I try to implement an java-ee App. I'm having some trouble to configure the persistence.xml. I want the default java h2:mem to be my persistence unit. Hier is my persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence 
            http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd"
    version="1.0">

    <persistence-unit name="customerDatabase">
        <description>My Customer-DB</description>
    </persistence-unit>
    <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS"
        pool-name="ExampleDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
        <connection-url>jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1</connection-url>
        <driver>h2</driver>
        <security>
            <user-name>sa</user-name>
            <password>sa</password>
        </security>
    </datasource>
    <drivers>
        <driver name="h2" module="com.h2database.h2">
            <xa-datasource-class>org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource</xa-datasource-class>
        </driver>
    </drivers>
</persistence>
```

It's something wrong with it because i'm getting the error:

```
cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'datasource'. One of '{"http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence":persistence-unit}' 
 is expected.
```

what does the persistence.xml miss?

I changed my provider and i'm now using hibernate... Now i'm getting errors from an other order. Can anybody helps?

```
11:21:46,092 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.persistenceunit."javaee7-master.war#customerDatabase": org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit."javaee7-master.war#customerDatabase": javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: customerDatabase] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:172)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:117)
    at org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:665)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:182)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: customerDatabase] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1249)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.access$600(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:120)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:860)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:850)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:425)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:849)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate4.TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.build(TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.java:44)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:154)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity: de.ostfalia.entity.Customer
    at org.hibernate.cfg.InheritanceState.determineDefaultAccessType(InheritanceState.java:277)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.InheritanceState.getElementsToProcess(InheritanceState.java:224)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:775)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processAnnotatedClassesQueue(Configuration.java:3845)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processMetadata(Configuration.java:3799)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1412)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1846)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:857)
    ... 12 more

11:21:46,098 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "javaee7-master.war")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.persistenceunit.\"javaee7-master.war#customerDatabase\"" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit.\"javaee7-master.war#customerDatabase\": javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: customerDatabase] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: customerDatabase] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity: de.ostfalia.entity.Customer"}}
11:21:46,197 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 34) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "postgresql-9.4-1203.jdbc42.jar" (runtime-name : "postgresql-9.4-1203.jdbc42.jar")
11:21:46,198 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 34) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "javaee7-master.war" (runtime-name : "javaee7-master.war")
11:21:46,200 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0183: Service status report
WFLYCTL0186:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.persistenceunit."javaee7-master.war#customerDatabase": org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit."javaee7-master.war#customerDatabase": javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: customerDatabase] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
```

Comment: persistence.xml doesn't "miss" anything. You miss reading what it is supposed to contain. That XSD at the top of your file tells you what you can put there http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd

Comment: Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: WFLYJPA0057: PersistenceProvider '
     org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider

Comment: and what does that have to do with anything in the "question"?

Comment: Nothing... I posted at the wrong place. It was for the suggestion below. sorry

Answer (score 1):

According to the official schema, the `<persistence>` element can only contain `persistence-unit` elements. I would suggest you start with upgrading from JPA 1.0 to 2.0 (requires Java 6) or 2.1 (requires Java 7). An example `persistence.xml` 2.1 would be as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="customerDatabase" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <non-jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS</non-jta-data-source>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.h2.Driver"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="sa"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="sa"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

This configuration presumes your application gets the `java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS` data source from some other configuration, like for example in Apache Tomcat, it would be in the `context.xml` and the properties listed in this example would not be necessary.
The provider is different if you're not using the EclipseLink library.
Also `non-jta-data-source` might have to be `jta-data-source` in your case.

update:

The error you are getting now comes from `No identifier specified for entity: de.ostfalia.entity.Customer`. You need to make sure all your entity classes have properly specified Id columns. If you are using JPA annotations, that would be the `@Id` annotation. You may also need a `@GeneratedValue` on it, if the database automatically assigns the ID on insert for that table (the most common case). There is also the option of specifying them through a `mapping.xml` file. These tutorials will get you started with good examples http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jpa/jpa_orm_components.htm http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077817/java-se/understanding-jpa-part-1-the-object-oriented-paradigm-of-data-persistence.html

One thing I learned the hard way is that every time you do `EntityManager em = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();` you must `em.close()` it in the end, no matter if you've committed or rolled-back the transaction, which means you must also catch any `Throwable`s that may occur. In our webapp, we do this by using a `javax.servlet.Filter` (only applies to webapps) for all urls. If you leave it open for too long with no activity, the database will eventually drop the connection (which might not happen in H2 specifically) and the thread becomes unusable until you restart the server.

Comment: Now it doesn't find the "org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider" where do i set it up?

Comment: Depends on what persistence library you're using, if you're using one at all. It doesn't come standard with Java runtime. How you set it up depends on your build system. I only know how it's done with Maven, but if you're developing under Netbeans, in most cases you can use the dependency menu to add them graphically.

Comment: I also use maven. But i read on the internet, that i'm just missing the Eclipse implementation of PersistenceProvider... I'll try to download the jar and see what next.

Comment: EclipseLink is supposedly the reference implementation, but I recommend Hibernate for just one extra that it supports: named parameters in native queries. That is not required, but also not forbidden by the JPA 2.1 standard.